# OpenCL 1.2 on mac os Big Sur 11.1

Tags: macos, opencl

How do i update the OpenCL version to 1.2 on mac.
clinfo is complaining as below. I'm running mac os Big Sur 11.1
and also have updated to the latest xcode.

```
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 1.0,
            but some installed platforms support OpenCL 1.2.
            Programs using 1.2 features may crash
            or behave unexpectedly
```